# What is the best way to test a mobile website in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, mobile-website

Does anyone have a good solution for testing mobile websites in Visual Studio 2010?

In VS 2008 I used to be able to start up a mobile emulator.  That functionality seems to be gone in 2010.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason they took it out I'm guessing is that there are NUMEROUS browser implementations for the mobile space.  Your best hope is to find a set of emulators for the largest platforms available(IPhone, BlackBerry, Droid...) where you can verify the experience for those users.  A single emulator will only do a poor job in gauging the experience for additional users on other platforms.

Answer (score 1):

i agree with Achilles, too many platforms too many devices. if this is a business project you can try http://www.deviceanywhere.com/ (not free). I personally ask friends to visit demo site and test